# Is norm a functional (rather than a function)?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Many authors of textbooks define the norm as a real-valued function that satisfies those well-known properties. For example, the definition of norm at Wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)). In my opinion, however, the norm is indeed a functional rather than a function, because it maps sequences, functions, or some other "vectors" from a vector space to a real number: $X \to \mathbb{R}$. The norm is a function if and only if $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Is my point of view wrong or the authors should improve the definition?

PS. I think the idea of functional is kind of extended from the idea of function. I think a function can only be a mapping from numbers to a number, while a functional can be a mapping from any *vectors* in vector space to a number. Those *vectors* can themselves be functions, thus someone calls functional as *function of function*. In my opinion, therefore, **functional is not a subset of function, but function is a subset of functional**. If we talk about the generalized idea of function with respect to the mapping functionality, shall we say a mapping or an operator?

Comment: Every functional is a function but not every function is a functional.

Comment: @user160738 Do you have a reference for that last statement? "Usually" in linear algebra maybe, but there is a world of uses beyond that.

Comment: @user160738 in linear algebra, yes, we want things to be linear. But there are functionals outside linear algebra where linearity is not a thing one really cares about e.g. $$L: C^1([0,1],\mathbb R^3)\rightarrow\mathbb R),~c\mapsto L(c):=\int\limits_{0}^{1} \Vert \dot{c}(t)\Vert\mathrm{d}t$$ (giving you the length of the curve $c$) is an example of a non-linear functional.

Answer (score 1):

From yout point of view it can be either a *function* and a *functional*... But only pay attention to the following question: is the concept of function more or less restrictive than the one of functional?

Taking the definition of norm, we have that given a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ (actaully can also be a *subfield*, but for the sake of simplicity we can state also in this way), a norm on $V$ is a *function* $n\colon V \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the usual properties of being absolutely homogeneous or absolutely scalable, being definite positive and making the triangle inequality hold.

If you now focus on what the vector space $V$ can be you can easily prove that, yes, continuous, discontinuous, $l^p$ functions and many others form a vector space. But they are only a very small part of what $V$ can be!

Greedily one could say: every function can be seen as a vector(at most, infinite dimensional) but not all vectors can be seen as function...

So you are right when you say that a norm can be seen as a functional but the notion of *function* is more general, so the latter is preferable. (By the way, we are mathematicians, we like define objects in the most general case :) )

Answer (score 1):

Removing psychological aspects of the question, if we define a functional to be a $\mathbb{R}$-valued or $\mathbb{C}$-valued or scalar-valued function, then a norm is a functional, and as such, a function.